# Can I set the altitude mode or extrude globally (only once)?

Tags: kml, google-earth

I want to use extrude/altitude `absolute` on my points. I can do this as below, but then I have to repeat this for every point (larger kml file).

Wonder if I can set this globally and only once?
As a kind of default value for `<Point>`.

```
<Placemark><Point><altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode><extrude>1</extrude><coordinates>9.38916000,49.83081000,8457.590000</coordinates></Point><name>1: 18:53:29.477 </name> .... </Placemark>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties `extrude` and `altitudeMode` are only defined in the context of a given geometry and KML does **not** provide a global setting that can be defined globally and inherited.

One option to make the KML file size smaller is add the KML file to a KMZ file so the file is compressed.

KML has the concept of inheritance and reuse to eliminate redundant elements as the following:

**1. shared styles**

KML has the concept of shared styles that can be defined once and reused in muiltiple placemark. The styles are global and it be referenced anywhere in the KML file by its "id".

**2. inheritance**

For convenience in constructing KML feature hierarchies the value of the following four elements are inherited by all Placemark, Folder, and Document members of a feature hierarchy. For more details see KML 2.2 Standard (section 9.6.2).

- atom:author
- atom:link
- kml:Region
- kml:AbstractTimePrimitiveGroup (e.g., TimeSpan or TimeStamp)

For example, if a Document or Folder has a Region element then that Region applies to all child Documents, Folders, and Placemarks unless the child explicitly defines its own region.

Answer (score 2):

Jason is correct that there's no way to set altitudeMode or extrude in one place in the KML and share it across all geometries, rather it needs to be applied in each geometry tag (Point, LineString, Polygon, etc.).

One relatively quick way to do this, if you're hand-editing the KML file in a text editor that supports it, is to use a Find and Replace-All tool. For example, you might use:

Find: `<Point>`

Replace with: `<Point><extrude>1</extrude><altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>`

If there is already another altitude mode set (for example: clampToGround), then you could do something simpler, like:

Find: `<altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>`

Replace with: `<extrude>1</extrude><altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>`

Also, note that in your example KML you have several tags in the wrong order, per the KML schema.  The `<name>` tag should be first after `<Placemark>`, and `<extrude>` should come before `<altitudeMode>`. Google Earth will ignore most issues like this, and still display the KML file, but it's good practice to follow the tag order in the schema to avoid unusual errors.  You can find the correct orders in the KML Reference, for example:

Placemark: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#placemark

and Point: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#point

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the order! Did not know the order matters.